# Dependency-driven self-building JS library

Tags: javascript

(I hope the question title is rather explanatory than misleading..)

I wonder if there is a JavaScript library/framework out there, which would parse and analyze the JS code written by web developer, and then synthesize the minimal necessary subset of the library into a single JS file, intended for deployment with this specific web app.

Comment: Like Google Closure Library and Compiler? You can also use the compiler without the library if you set up your code properly. https://developers.google.com/closure/

Comment: As @FelixKling said, Google Closure is the way to go.